# Roku : Writing to Registry

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

When writing values to the registry, does this really have to be done using a task [Task](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Task)  ?

Snippet from https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Support

- roRegistry :     Can only be used in a Task node
- roRegistrySection :  Can only be used in a Task node

I've written to the registry successfully with and without the use of a Task.

Answer (score 3):

Well only because you can doesn't mean you should! Writing to registry should be done only in task since doing it that way ensures that Your UI will not be blocked while writing data to the registry. It's a bad practice to write data to registry from the render thread.

EDIT: I would just like to add official response from ROKU on this subject and 8.0 version of the ROKU OS where they recommend using the TASK still.
This stack overflow question/thread is mentioned there as well.
https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Developer-Program/Registry-and-Task-Nodes/td-p/497169

Comment: yeah I figured, I understand  that there is a possibility of blocking the UI if a large amount data is being written to the registtry.   I just think its a bit of overkill to have to set up a task and callback to write a simple string value to the registry.  Anyhow , gracias and I will use a Task as suggested.

Comment: The documentation is just wrong/outdated. The docs are not recommending to use a Task for performance reasons, they are stating that the `roRegistry` and `roRegistrySection` components can ONLY be used in a task thread, this was true prior to firmware 8.0, they just haven't updated the docs.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla , so it's not necessary to use a Task to write to registry ?

Comment: @Fabii Correct, not necessary anymore, and you will probably not see any performance issues by doing so.

Comment: FYI, `ReadAsciiFile()` can be used in the render thread as well since firmware 8.0.

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla You should write an explicit answer to help others find correct information.

Answer (score 3):

No, a Task node is not required to use the `roRegistry` or the `roRegistrySection` components, the documentation is just wrong/outdated.

Prior to firmware 8.0 a Task node was required, but that is not the case anymore. Both components can safely be used in the render thread.

`ReadAsciiFile()` can also be used in the render thread since firmware 8.0 and they haven't updated that either.